# Quebra de linha em dados vindo de uma lista

Tags: java, primefaces

Tenho um dialog que mostra na tela os dados recebidos de uma lista:

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <h:outputText value="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}"/> <br />
</p:dialog>
```

Quando esse dialog é exibido, todas as informações aparecem na mesma linha, e eu queria que fosse um dado em cada linha.

Alguém sabe como faço isso?

Comment: Acredito que a String que vc quer mostrar já tenha as quebras de linha. Nesse caso use um `<p:inputTextArea />` ao invés do outputText.

Comment: Já tentou usar o `dataList`? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não especificou o que vai fazer com a lista (creio que seja somente para exibição, mas a mesma lógica se aplica a outras estruturas - checkboxes, por exemplo), existem várias soluções possíveis (considerando que getVendedoresPorZona retorna uma lista de String). Nos exemplos, estou usando o outputText da sua pergunta para fins didáticos:

Por Repeat (permite uma maior flexibidade, não ficando restrito a um output específico):

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <ui:repeat value="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}" var="v">
        <h:outputText value="#{v}"/><br />
    </ui:repeat>
</p:dialog>
```

Por [Repeat](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/repeat.xhtml) do Primefaces:

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <p:repeat value="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}" var="v">
        <h:outputText value="#{v}"/><br />
    </p:repeat>
</p:dialog>
```

Por [DataList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml) do Primefaces:

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <p:dataList value="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}" var="v" itemType="disc">
        <h:outputText value="#{v}"/>
    </p:dataList>
</p:dialog>
```

Por [DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) do Primefaces (útil quando tem um objeto com vários atributos):

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <p:dataTable value="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}" var="v">
        <p:column headerText="Vendedor">
            <h:outputText value="#{v}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

Por ForEach (exemplificado anteriormente pelo @arthur-vidal):

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">
    <c:forEach var="v" items="${zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}">
        <h:outputText value="#{v}"/><br />
    </c:forEach>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que esteja exibindo tudo na mesma linha porque o "< /br >" é executada somente uma vez e depois de exibir o outputText.
Tenta colocar o retorno dessa lista dentro de um forEach.

Exemplo:

```
<p:dialog header="#{zona.nome}" widgetVar="vendedores" minHeight="40">    
    <c:forEach  items="#{zonaBean.getVendedoresPorZona(zona.id)}" var="row"  
       <h:outputText value="row"/> <br />
    </c:forEach>
</p:dialog>
```