# DataTable dinâmico com Primefaces 6 + Exibir Objetos na mesma linha

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Boa tarde Pessoal, olhei o showcase do primefaces e não achei uma solução.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte tenho uma lista de contas abertas e gostaria de ao clicar abrir uma pagina mostrando as constas abertas, mas uma ao lado da outra no DataTable. O mesmo esquema de gerenciamento de mesas. Ex.:

```
     contas abertas
```

Conta 1  conta 2  conta 3 conta 4

conta 5  conta 6  conta 7 conta 8...

Cada conta seria um botão onde poderia clicar pra interagir.
Alguém poderia me dar uma força, por favor? Usando JSF2.2 + Primefaces 6

Comment: Veja se algum desses exemplos ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169718/uirepeat-pegando-a-descricao-no-banco/169839#169839 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170291/quebra-de-linha-em-dados-vindo-de-uma-lista/171026#171026 sendo que vc pode iterar outro componente, como por exemplo `commandButton` para executar a ação que vc quer.

Comment: Olá Marcus, O DataGrid do PrimeFaces atendeu a minha necessidade.